# How do I get the pipboy app to connect to my Xbox one?

Tags: fallout-4, xbox-smartglass

I am trying to set-up the pipboy smart phone app. I can scan and find my console but it fails after I sign-in. I know I'm signing in correctly and once I do get past the sign-in screen, it gives me standard troubleshooting tips for the smart-glass, all of which I've followed but without success. I do have the Xbox smart-glass app as well, which works fine, so I'm not sure what is causing the problem here.

Comment: It might matter what kind of phone you're using. I did this with my Samsung Galaxy S4 Active with no problem at all. You say the phone finds the console fine, so I assume your network setup is okay.

Comment: One thing to consider, having tried this, I noticed right away that although it may be cool to use the pip-boy app, using it as such does not pause the game like going into your in-game pip-boy does. You've been warned. :)

Comment: Just a sanity check, do you have 'Pip-Boy App Enabled' set to 'On' in the Gameplay section of the settings menu in Fallout 4?

Answer (score 2):

There are directions for this on [Bethesda's website](http://help.bethesda.net/app/answers/detail/a_id/31476/~/how-do-i-connect-the-fallout-4-pip-boy-app-to-my-game%3F):

> 1. Open the game.
> 2. Navigate to Settings, then Gameplay.
> 3. Switch the "Pip-Boy App Enabled" option to On.

[image]

> 4. Exit and restart the game.